# Dictionary replaces previous values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with a dictionary but instead of replacing the values inside i want to add new values to it, below is what i have right now which replaces my existing values inside the dictionary with new ones.

sample values

```
source: something.txt
    suspicious_key: GFATGTFBFD
        startPos: 23
        endPos:32
```

what changes after that is the addition of new `suspicious_key`,`startPos` and `endPos` for same document

```
source: something.txt

    suspicious_key: GFATGTFBFD
        startPos: 23
        endPos:32

    <<<<Second entry under same key>>>>

    suspicious_key: GKDTFSFSAS
        startPos: 32
        endPos:45

dictionary[source] = {suspicious_key: {"startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end}}
```

i want to add another set of values under the same source for suspicious key, startPos, endPos

i tried with `update()` but does not seem to work.

```
dictionary[source].update({suspicious_key: {"startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end}})
```

How should i go about it?

Comment: So how do you know that `dict.update()` "does not seem to work"? What output where you expecting, and what did you get instead?

Answer (score 1):

Your `dict.update()` updates the wrong dictionary; it effectively does *exactly the same thing* as assigning to the one `suspicious_key` key.

Update the dictionary the `suspicious_key` key references instead:

```
dictionary[source][suspicious_key].update({"startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end})
```

If that key may be missing, use the `dict.setdefault()` method to insert an empty dictionary for you:

```
dictionary[source].setdefault(
    suspicious_key, {}).update(
    {"startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end})
```

Now the `startPos` and `endPos` keys will be added to the nested dictionary, rather than replacing the nested dictionary altogether.

Comment: yeah but this way the key must be the same if i understand correctly, right? in my case i want to add new suspicious_keys, startPos, endPos not just startPos,endPos. The suspicious_key will never be missing but it will be different than previous one

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou: please *add sample input and output* to your question then, because it is not clear what you are expecting. With some sample input and output I can even build you a quick demo of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want the list of objects stored in your dictionary?

I assume for each source you want to get a bunch of objects identified by suspicious_key.

adding first item:

```
dictionary[source] = [{suspicious_key: {"startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end}}]
```

then when you want to add next items:

```
dictionary[source].append({suspicious_key: {"startPos":index_start, "endPos": index_end}})
```

as a result you when you ask for dictionary[source] you will get a list of objects.

Comment: thank for your input, now i get this though, 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: the append method comes form the list object which is stored in the dictionary